# Is there any use case for docker -t option without providing -i?

Tags: docker

As I know most of the times `-t` would be used in conjunction with `-i` to get an interactive terminal. I was wondering if there is any use case for docker `-t` without providing `-i`.

Why not having an option `-x` for interactive so we can pipe something to docker and another `-y` for interactive terminal. What `-t` is capable of doing alone?

In other words what is the use case of a tty when you can't use it to input something.

Comment: Please leave a comment while down voting so I know  what is wrong with the question and how to make it more clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful for one off commands. For example, to make sure your container is running in the right folder, you could do `docker exec it (id) pwd`. Or perhaps some sort of in-container script or something else. Generally though I think the uses are limited more, but not everything requires interaction.